# Java regex results characters instead of words

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing code to filter the classes and ids from minified css file in Java, but i'm stuck at writing the regex for it. I wrote it on the regexr website and i'm converting it to Java, but it gives me chars as result instead of the words. 
my regex/java code looks like:

```
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
         Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z#-_](?![^{]*})")
             .matcher(cssLine);
         String line = "";
         while (m.find()) {
           allMatches.add(m.group());
         }
```

When i print all items from the array i get a result like

```
    a
    v
    a
    d
```

The input is like this:

```
/*HEADER*/header{height:180px;} header.fixed{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;height:70px;width:100%;display:block;z-index:1000;background-color:white;-webkit-transition:width2s,height0.2s;transition:width2s,height0,2s;} header.fixed.logo-background{background-image:url('../img/WEB_MOBILE_03.jpg');background-size:auto80%;background-position:auto5%;-webkit-transition:width2s,height0.2s;transition:width2s,height0,2s;}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't just give me the chunks of chars like "header.fixed"?

Comment: Use a parser not regex

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please also note that the third dash in the square brackets should be moved to the last position: `[a-zA-Z#_-]`. Otherwise the class definition includes anything between `#` and `_` and this range contains `;`, `:` `?` for example, which you're not likely want to match here.

Comment: Ok, try `[a-zA-Z#_-]++(?![^{}]*})` - does it work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added **+** to your regex, so it's now `([a-zA-Z#-_]+)(?![^{]*})`.

**Output**

```
/*HEADER*/header
header.fixed
header.fixed.logo-background
```